# Formatting in HTML vs CSS in epub

Tags: html, css, tags, epub

I've been looking around a little and haven't found an answer to this question.
I am making an epub book and I've no idea what is the most adequate practice, if style italic, bold or underlined text in the html file, using `<i>`, `<b>` and `<u>` tags or define this in a class in the styles sheet.
Can somebody clarify this to me, please?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. For example, in a paragraph, if the developer only wishes to make some text *italic*, then there is no reason to create a class for it. However, if there is a specific case where text must have a format while inside of a specific tag structure, this is when you should create a class.

> Use a CSS Class

```
<div id="important">
    <p>This should always be italic under this condition</p>
    <p>And so should this</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>But this should not</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>And maybe I want to have multiple styles at once. <span class="underline-bold-italic">Use a class</span></p>
</div>
```

> Use A Tag

```
<p>Hmmm... <i>this</i> may be important.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think whichever is used, it should be consistent. Remember you can override the effect an `<i>` tag will have by adding appropriate CSS. If you decide later on that everything italic should also be red, you only want to change that in one place.